# Replace values inside foreach loop and show only one string - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, replace, foreach, str-replace

I want to replace my values of string according to the position coming from JSON array.
e.g. JSON has 0,3,6 numbers coming as offset(position) attribute. I want to get each value from my loop and make it replaceable inside my string. But Its getting only last value outside loop that is '6'(offset) and replacing 'c' with red color variable 'c'.
Here's my  code:

```
function str_replace_first($search, $replace, $subject)
    {
        $search = '/'.preg_quote($search, '/').'/';
        return preg_replace($search, $replace, $subject, 1);
    }

$str =  "we is chekin"; 
foreach ($json2['matches'] as $key=>$val) {
    $takeoffset = $val['offset'];    // getting offset value from JSON
    $convertingoffset = $str[$takeoffset]; //convert number to character
    $ofsetsplit = '<span style="color: red;">'.$convertingoffset.'</span>';  //value to replace
    $realone = $convertingoffset;    //value to be replaced
     $result_offset = str_replace_first($realone, $ofsetsplit, $str); //replacing
}
echo $result_offset; //getting result
```

When I replace inside loop:

[image]

When I replace outside loop, then only last value of position showing changed only
[image]

Comment: So you are saying that `$json2['matches']` is `0,3,6` But is it an array or a string? PLease show us a `var_dump($json2['matches'] )`

Comment: There's no need for `$spltary`, you can index the string dfirectly.

Comment: You're overwriting the variable each time, rather than merging each change with the previous replacements.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, you're right. Even without splitting its working. Actually I'm not overwriting. on first variable I'm storing values in red color. And on second storing them as default color. Now, I want to replace those red values with those black ones. My main concern is to replace them all once not again and again in each iteration.

Comment: @RiggsFolly actually matches has the arrays. And all arrays has the offset attribute which holds the position number.

Comment: `str_replace()` can be given an arrays of strings to match and replacement strings, and it will do all the replacements at once.

Comment: Are you even getting the replacements you want? Your second replacement has offset=3, but it's replacing the `i` at offset 3 and 11, because `str_replace()` replaces all matches of `i`. It doesn't know that you got it from `$str[3]` and only want to replace that one.

Comment: Have echoed my offset value that I'm calling inside $takeoffset variable: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZLEJoyECNj_-8DmOCPO0H31hYqf_Yzsr/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/352329).   Why aren't you just using a pattern which will target all first letters?